# What is the prior distribution in a multinomial logistic regression (UPG package in R, Bayesian statistics)?

Tags: r, bayesian, generalized-linear-model, multinomial-logit, mlogit

In my thesis I want to compare the frequentist and bayesian approach, specifically in doing a multinomial logistic regression. I have had only a few lectures on Bayesian statistics during my bachelors, so I have watched lectures and read a lot of stuff in order to better comprehend this approach to statistics.

I have already performed a multinomial logistic regression with the mlogit (frequentist) and vglm (frequentist) packages, but now I was trying to do this with the UPG package (https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02506). It is working and although I still need to interpret the results, I have one question which I would really like to know the answer to:

The Bayesian approach begins with the specification of the prior probability distribution. However, when I was working with the UPG package I did not include such a prior probability distribution. How does this work? Is this selected automatically or can I specify a prior probability distribution? Or is this not possible in a multinomial logistic regression? I am a bit confused since I thought that one of the advantages of Bayesian statistics is that prior knowledge can be included into the model. Any insight would be very appreciated!

(Any other tips for papers/lectures etc. concerning a Bayesian approach to multinomial logistic regression are also very welcome, I do not fully comprehend it yet, especially the output of the UPG package)

Answer (score 1):

The manual https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UPG/UPG.pdf (or try `?UPG`) suggests there are parameters `A0, B0, D0, d0, G0` which help specify the prior and have default values which you seem to have implicitly used.

The vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/UPG/vignettes/vignette.pdf goes into more detail, saying things like

> **4.5. Further details**
>
> The estimation of binary, multinomial and binomial logit models requires simulating from Pólya Gamma distributions. This is accomplished using an implementation in **pgdraw** (Makalic and Schmidt 2016). In terms of prior distributions, the elements of $\mathbf β$ are assumed to follow independent Gaussian distributions a priori. In order to change the prior variances, the parameters `A0` and `B0` of the `UPG` function are available, refering to the variances of the intercept and the remaining coefficients, respectively. Both A0 and B0 have 4 as default value.